# Filtering a massive pyspark dataframe, errors on .show() method after successful execution

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to filter a PySpark dataframe by whether or not a column value is present in a list of values (otherwise filter the row out.)

Here's what I have and the corresponding error:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
reduced = r.filter((f.col('movie_id') in movie_ids))\
    .filter((f.col('user_id') in user_ids))

>>>>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-76440ab49160> in <module>()
      1 import pyspark.sql.functions as f
      2 
----> 3 reduced = r.filter((f.col('movie_id') in movie_ids))    .filter((f.col('user_id') in user_ids))

/content/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in __nonzero__(self)
    688 
    689     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 690         raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
    691                          "'~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.")
    692     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Likewise, I've tried the following, but it seems to trigger an error later down the road

```py
reduced = r.where(r.movie_id.isin(movie_ids)).where(r.user_id.isin(user_ids))
# Executes without issues...

reduced.show()
```

And then this rather long error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-0fa28162e68e> in <module>()
----> 1 reduced.show()

4 frames
/content/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o130535.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 1320, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:163)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readFully(FSInputChecker.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.readChunk(ChecksumFileSystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:196)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readCustomLine(LineReader.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:156)
    ... 28 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:163)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readFully(FSInputChecker.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.readChunk(ChecksumFileSystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:196)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readCustomLine(LineReader.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:156)
    ... 28 more
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Maybe the volume is just too much for google colab

Comment: there are limit on the length of SQL query strings. if the lists of movie_ids and/or user_ids are very long, try to create them as separate dataframes and then take `left_semi` join.

Comment: @jxc, yes - huge recommender system. Each list has 50,000 elements. Because of its volume, I chose to use Spark. For context, there were originally ~900,000 unique movies and users. This is my attempt to sample of movies and users to scale the problem down.

Comment: @jbuddy_13: jxc is right and he's trying to tell you it's not a good idea to use `isin` with a huge list as the parameter. In that case, you want that list of parameters to be its own DataFrame (one row per member of the list) and to join (type=left_semi) the two DataFrames.
FYI, `in` is a reserved Python keyword that should not be confused with the `isin` method available on Columns. The first error you're getting is related to the wrong choice of operator (`in`, instead of `isin`).